# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:"_OBJC_CLASS_$_KTKRegion", referenced from: objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o

Tags: ios, iphone

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_KTKRegion", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_KTKLocationManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: You probably forgot to add KTKRegion.m to your project build. Or if you did, clean solution and rebuild.

Comment: ya added it @Cœur. But same result.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your target links `libkontakt-ios-sdk.a`. You can find Kontact's instructions for setting up your project [here](http://developer.kontakt.io/ios-sdk/quickstart/).